# Trying to set AWS HealtchCheck URL to webmethod

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to get my head around Application Health Check URL.

Is there a way to make it check a specific webmethod in the application. What I'm trying to do is link the healthcheck to disk usage.

I tried writing a webmethod which I can access using a simple url:

`https://somewhere.com/test/healthcheck`

which just checks the disk space and returns a string `OK`

this works fine, but when setting the Health check URL to  `/test/healthcheck` the environment goes from Green to Red and the site is unreachable (returns a `503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity`

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is using `/Test/HealthCheck` not `/test/healthcheck`. Does your application respond the same to both requests? Also, check the load balancer to see why it says the health check is failing.

Comment: yes the application responds to both requests.

Comment: it just says Elastic Load Balancer XXXXXXX has zero healthy instances.